# Is it possible to create a master page which selects another master page?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have a master page with name `MasterPage.master`.

Now I want to create another master page (`MasterPage2.master`) that its `MasterPageFile` is `MasterPage.master`,
But when I create `MasterPage2` and then create a webform from `MasterPage2`, there isn't any `ContentPlaceHolder` in this webform.

Please explain for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is *nested master pages*.
Google it and you'll have a ton of tutorials. Top 2 results from google:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2b3ktt7(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2b3ktt7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb547109(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb547109%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I'm sorry that I ask a duplicate question. I didn't know how I must search. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Most likely either:

- MasterPage2 is using the `ContentPlaceHolder` from MasterPage but not adding another `ContentPlaceHolder` for your content page to use
- the `ContentPlaceHolder` on MasterPage2 has the same IDs as the one on MasterPage

Make sure MasterPage2 has a `ContentPlaceHolder` with a unique identifier.